# Don't render admin menus and Joomla stuff in my back-end component?

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, administrator

Is there a way that Joomla only renders my component. I would like to prevent that the admin menu is shown, but also that moo-tools(collides and slows down all!) and jQuery doesn't get loaded.

My application uses the admin component url also for RPC/Ajax so I don't really want a to open a new RPC entry-point...

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest & quickest way:

1.- remove all scripts:

```
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
foreach($doc->_scripts as $key => $script) {
    foreach($search as $findme) {
        unset($doc->_scripts[$key]);
    }
}
```

2. then determine all toolbars, etc... via inspector, then hide it via CSS